# Using improbable premise(s) to reach a conclusion

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, logic

Is there a name for a fallacy that involves using an improbable premise or premises to reach a desired conclusion? For example saying (exaggerated to better convey what is meant): "You should always have a truckload of provisions at home even in the spring because you never know, it might snow heavily at any time during the year and trap you in your home." I know I can always say the speaker is being paranoid or just ridiculous, but I am looking for a more polite and formal word, preferably the name of the logical fallacy involved.

Answer (score 2):

***[Specious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/specious)*** is an adjective which could describe a seemingly well-reasoned, even plausible, but still fallacious argument.

It means having an attractive appearance which can deceive.

I found it while looking up ***[non sequitur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non_sequitur)***, which is Latin for *"it does not follow*".

Answer (score -1):

What about "**begging the question**", which means the question is assuming its own conclusion?  Like saying to buy provisions so someone won't be worried about being trapped by snow unprepared at any time of the year - and as for why one should be worried about being hit by a snowstorm at any time of year, because it is natural to worry if someone isn't prepared (by buying provisions).

It's a kind of circular logic, and there's probably better examples out there, but it boils down to "the answer is X, because Y.  why assume Y?  Because then the answer is X".

Maybe there's a better fit, but this is what I thought of first.